# Why does NSString become empty (without reason)?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am going crazy with Objective C. Please look to the following code.

FirstViewController.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *button;
    NSString* superString;
}

- (IBAction)buttonDown;
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    superString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @"A_super_string_file.txt"];
    [self buttonDown];
}

- (IBAction)buttonDown {
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:superString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
    [textView setText:text];
}
```

1. Run the application. A_super_string_file.txt successfully displayed in textView.
2. Press the button. The application crashes because superString refers on the same address as in the step 1 but there is another variable or nothing on this address. Print Description on superString displays nothing or random other variable (may be even different type).

What happens? I am a skill developer but have no idea in this case. Thanks a lot for help!

UPDATE: Possibly, it's hidden autorelease in the work. But when it releases memory? On different moment every time or on some exact moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain superString.

```
[superString retain];
```

immediately after creating it.

and then release it in dealloc.

Answer (score 4):

`NSString`'s +`stringWithFormat`: is autoreleasing. You need to retain it if you want it to stay around.

Properties are a good way to do this, because it cuts down how much memory management you need to worry about yourself.

.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *button;
    NSString* superString;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* superString;

- (IBAction)buttonDown;
```

.m

```
@synthesize superString

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setSuperString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", @"A_super_string_file.txt"]];
    [self buttonDown];
}

- (IBAction)buttonDown {
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:superString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
    [textView setText:text];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [superString release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried to use a property. But I set it by "superString = ..." instead "[self setSuperString:...]". The string autoreleased too. Is there an important difference between two ways to set string's value?

Comment: When you use a property, the easiest thing to remember is to set it with `self` - as in `self.superString = newString`

Comment: Without the self. or [self Set..] you're not using the property. That's the important difference.